# Defra LiDAR - Convert DTM to PointCloud?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, dem, lidar, lastools

Defra has DSM and DTM data for Blackwell in Birmingham, but no Point Cloud data.  I am trying to get LiDAR Point Cloud data to build a golf course model (in TGC2019) for Blackwell, and this uses ChadsTool, and this tool requires Point Cloud format data.

How can I convert DTM to Point Cloud?  Apparently LasTools might be able to do this, and I can download the exes, but I do not know how to convert.  The DTM files seem to have large TIFF files in them, and these  are probably 'the data', if that helps.

Comment: No, this is not possible.  The point cloud data are a distribution of LiDAR strike points over the surface.  The DTM and DSM are transformations of those data into a regular tessellation of pixels representing the (statistically highest and lowest) elevations within those pixels.  You could convert the DTM and DSM to points, and probably combine those point back into an LAS file type, but this is not the same thing as the original point cloud data.  Contact the LiDAR vendor for the point cloud data.

Comment: I assume that by "point cloud" you mean LAS? If this is not the case then you are working with a proprietary format and open-access software will do you little good. Aside from the binary LAS format, there is a common ASCII X,Y,Z format that many software can read. Please also keep in mind that, converting a raster to points does not result in what would be considered a point cloud. But, depending on what a given software does with the data, it may not matter.

Comment: @GBG The vendor is the British Government, Defra agency, and they post what they have, so if it is not there, they usually don't have it.  I don't mind that the conversion from DTM would not be the original point cloud, as I just need terrain data for a video game rendering of a golf course.  As long as I end with an approximate LAS, I would be happy.  Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I do indeed mean LAS.  I don't mind if the result is not strictly a point cloud, I just need a height map in LAS format to feed into another tool.  Do you know how I might convert DTM (tif format) into LAS, using the LASTools utilities?  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: See this link for some help converting TIFF to LAS:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264913/converting-tiff-file-to-las-file-in-qgis

Comment: For others; Further to this, I have used LasTools Demzip.exe to convert format, and then lasground_new.exe to add ground classification, and managed to get a las point-cloud file from DTM data.  Martin Isenberg deserves great credit.