# Merging .asc without conversion to GeoTIFF

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, convert, las, ascii

I have a lot of LiDAR data in the format of .asc, however not all of the data is needed for my study area. To get just the data I want, I have merged the .asc files before clipping them with a mask vector layer in QGIS.

I now have the data for the areas I require, however it is now in the format of a GeoTIFF (from the merge process). Is there a way I could do these steps differently so that the data remains in .asc format?

Conversion into LAS rather than ASCII would also work, I just want to avoid GeoTIFF format as it limits the analysis I can perform on this data.

I did see on [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264913/converting-tiff-file-to-las-file-in-qgis/264980#264980) that you can convert GeoTIFFs directly to LAS or other formats using [PDAL](https://pdal.io/en/latest/), however I can't get my head around how to use this.

Comment: When you did this in QGIS, did it give you a command-line equivalent? If so, show that and you might be able to tweak it to output to ASC instead of geotiff. I'd never heard of pdal, I think QGIS uses gdal, which can also do this conversion.

Comment: Asc is a very poor format to store data in. Geotiff is much faster for display and access. Pretty much any geospatial tool should be able to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS with GDAL has the option of gdal2xyz. You can find it in the Processing Toolbox.